# How do I setup Postfix to discard email sent to an alias in a MySQL virtual alias table?

Tags: postfix

I'm trying to setup Postfix to discard mail when there is an alias record in the MySQL address that forwards the mail to user `nobody`.

All mail that is sent to `discardme@domain.com` should be black-holed.

Instead, when a database record is set to forward an address to `nobody`, **I** get the message forwarded to me at my personal email `myemail@otherdomain.com` instead!

The alias database is working correctly:

```
postmap -q discardme@domain.com mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/aliases.cf
nobody
```

Aliases are setup:

```
cat /etc/aliases
nobody: /dev/null
```

I've run `newaliases`.

I'm not seeing anything in the logs that explains why the mail goes to me:

```
tail -f /var/log/mail.log -n0 | grep discardme@domain.com
< unknown[xx.xx.xx.xx]: RCPT TO:<discardme@domain.com>
extract_addr: input: <discardme@domain.com>
smtpd_check_addr: addr=discardme@domain.com
send attr address = discardme@domain.com
input attribute value: discardme@domain.com
rewrite_clnt: local: discardme@domain.com -> discardme@domain.com
send attr address = discardme@domain.com
input attribute value: discardme@domain.com
resolve_clnt: `myemail@otherdomain.com' -> `discardme@domain.com' -> transp=`lmtp' host=`inet:[xx]:xx' rcpt=`discardme@domain.com' flags= class=virtual
ctable_locate: install entry key myemail@otherdomain.com?discardme@domain.com
extract_addr: in: <discardme@domain.com>, result: discardme@domain.com
ctable_locate: leave existing entry key myemail@otherdomain.com?discardme@domain.com
maps_find: recipient_canonical_maps: discardme@domain.com: not found
mail_addr_find: discardme@domain.com -> (not found)
maps_find: canonical_maps: discardme@domain.com: not found
mail_addr_find: discardme@domain.com -> (not found)
```

Here we see it finds the `nobody` alias in the MySQL database:

```
maps_find: virtual_alias_maps: mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql/aliases.cf(0,lock|fold_fix|utf8_request): discardme@domain.com = nobody
mail_addr_find: discardme@domain.com -> nobody
ctable_locate: leave existing entry key myemail@otherdomain.com?discardme@domain.com
milter_macro_lookup: result "discardme@domain.com"
ctable_locate: leave existing entry key myemail@otherdomain.com?discardme@domain.com
ctable_locate: leave existing entry key myemail@otherdomain.com?discardme@domain.com
milter8_rcpt_event: milter local:opendkim/opendkim.sock: rcpt <discardme@domain.com>
event: SMFIC_RCPT; macros: {rcpt_addr}=discardme@domain.com {rcpt_host}=inet:[redacted] {rcpt_mailer}=lmtp
```

And here it decides to deliver the mail to me instead of discarding it:

```
D27032507A: to=<myemail@otherdomain.com>, orig_to=<discardme@domain.com>, relay=[redacted], delay=0.47, delays=0.15/0/0.19/0.13, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 <myemail@otherdomain.com> 4u2+BSk8XWWpDwAA0J78UA Saved)
```

I am sending the test email to `discardme@domain.com` from `myemail@otherdomain.com`. But there is no alias setup that should cause me to receive any mail  for `domain.com` at my email address @ `otherdomain.com`.

How can I make Postfix discard mail sent to `discardme@domain.com` rather than forwarding it all to me?

**UPDATE**

The problem is related to Postfix not being able to deliver mail to local users.

If I use just `nobody` in the alias table as the destination, it gets re-written as `nobody@domain.com`, where domain.com is the value of `myhostname` in `main.cf`.

If I set the forward record to point to `nobody@localhost`, then mail bounces with:

```
<nobody@localhost> (expanded from <discardme@domain.com>):
    mail for localhost loops back to myself
```

Answer (score 0):

In the virtual aliases table, make the alias `@localhost`, ie:

```
discardme@domain.com -> trash@localhost
```

If you just use `trash` it will resolve to `trash@domain.com` which will forward to the wrong place or fail.

Also, make sure that the `local` daemon is enabled in `master.cf` and that `localhost` is in the list of local destinations:

```
mydestination = localhost
```